# Update record using instead of trigger in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, triggers

I have trigger in sql server 2005
which checks for duplicate record and then update the record.

```
USE [CheckeCon]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tgUserRoleExistForUpdate] ON [dbo].[Sec_UserRoles]
INSTEAD OF Update
AS
declare @UserRoleId int, @UserId int,@RoleId int, @FromDate datetime,@ToDate datetime,@CntlCreatedBy nvarchar,@CntlModifiedAt nvarchar,@CntlCurLockNo smallint;
select @UserRoleId=i.UserRoleId from inserted i;
select @UserId=i.UserId from inserted i;
select @RoleId=i.RoleId from inserted i;
select @FromDate=i.FromDate from inserted i;
select @ToDate=i.ToDate from inserted i;
select @CntlCreatedBy=i.CntlCreatedBy from inserted i;
select @CntlModifiedAt=i.CntlModifiedAt from inserted i;
select @CntlCurLockNo=i.CntlCurLockNo from inserted i;
BEGIN
-- BEGIN TRAN
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Sec_UserRoles SEUR
    JOIN    inserted i ON  
            SEUR.RoleId =  i.RoleId
    AND     SEUR.UserId = i.UserId
    Where i.FromDate BETWEEN SEUR.FromDate AND SEUR.ToDate
)
Update Sec_UserRoles Set UserId = @UserId,RoleId = @RoleId,FromDate = @FromDate,ToDate = @ToDate,
        CntlCreatedBy = @CntlCreatedBy,CntlModifiedAt = @CntlModifiedAt,CntlCurLockNo = @CntlCurLockNo Where  UserRoleId = @UserRoleId 
--Commit;
Else
    RAISERROR('User Role Association Already Present',15,1);
   --ROLLBACK; 
End
```

But the problem is that it can not update record only raised error which i given in trigger.
how can i update record using trigger?

Comment: Your code just assumes that the trigger will be called once for each row. This is **not** the case in SQL Server. If your `UPDATE` statement affects multiple rows, the trigger will be called **once for the statement** and your `Inserted` pseudo table will contain **multiple rows** - so your assignments here `select @UserRoleId = i.UserRoleId from inserted i;` will just assign an arbitrary value from the `Inserted` table and ignore all other rows in `Inserted` ....

Comment: No, no, no, no, no, no, NO. `inserted` can contain, 0, 1, or multiple rows. All of those `select @scalarvariable=...` statements might select values from *different* rows. And for your `IF EXISTS` test, there may be *some* rows for which the existence test returns true, and *some* rows for which it's false.

Answer (score 0):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tgUserRoleExistForUpdate] 

    ON [dbo].[Sec_UserRoles]
    INSTEAD OF UPDATE

AS BEGIN

    IF NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM INSERTED
    ) RAISERROR('NO ROW IN INSERTED', 16, 1)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    DECLARE 
          @UserRoleId INT
        , @UserId INT
        , @RoleId INT
        , @FromDate DATETIME
        , @ToDate DATETIME
        , @CntlCreatedBy NVARCHAR(MAX)
        , @CntlModifiedAt NVARCHAR(MAX)
        , @CntlCurLockNo SMALLINT

    DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL READ_ONLY FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT 
              i.UserRoleId
            , i.UserId
            , i.RoleId
            , i.FromDate
            , i.ToDate
            , i.CntlCreatedBy
            , i.CntlModifiedAt
            , i.CntlCurLockNo 
        FROM INSERTED i

    OPEN cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO
          @UserRoleId
        , @UserId
        , @RoleId
        , @FromDate
        , @ToDate
        , @CntlCreatedBy
        , @CntlModifiedAt
        , @CntlCurLockNo

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        IF NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM dbo.Sec_UserRoles s
            WHERE @FromDate BETWEEN s.FromDate AND s.ToDate
                AND s.RoleId = @RoleId
                AND s.UserId = @UserId
                --AND s.UserRoleId = @UserRoleId 
        )
        BEGIN

            UPDATE dbo.Sec_UserRoles 
            SET 
                  UserId = @UserId
                , RoleId = @RoleId
                , FromDate = @FromDate
                , ToDate = @ToDate
                , CntlCreatedBy = @CntlCreatedBy
                , CntlModifiedAt = @CntlModifiedAt
                , CntlCurLockNo = @CntlCurLockNo 
            WHERE UserRoleId = @UserRoleId 

        END
        ELSE BEGIN

             RAISERROR('User Role Association Already Present', 0, 1) -- 15      

        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO
              @UserRoleId
            , @UserId
            , @RoleId
            , @FromDate
            , @ToDate
            , @CntlCreatedBy
            , @CntlModifiedAt
            , @CntlCurLockNo

    END

    CLOSE cur
    DEALLOCATE cur

END
```

Comment: As I point out in my comment, there may be *some* rows in `inserted` for which the `EXISTS()` is true, and *other* rows in `inserted` for which it's false. It ought to be turned into a `WHERE` clause condition of some sort on the `UPDATE`.

Comment: You're welcome @MonaliJ. In case this solution fully suits you, I would be glad if you could confirm it.

Comment: i tried this solution, but still it does not update the record, still raised exception....

Comment: Please try updated query. Possible this remove your exception.